# Where are the .Net data types stored?

Tags: .net, types

Where are the .Net data types stored?

Comment: @Bhaskar : Hi Bhaskar, instead of using 'stored' you should have used word 'defined'. This'd help others understand the question better. The question should actuall form like this: "Where are the .net CTS types defined ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All core CTS types like Int16, Int32, Int64, String , Byte and etc. are defined in MSCorLib.dll. This file can be found in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 directory.

All other special purpose types and classes are stored in their respective FCL [Framework Class Library] Assemblies. Like all types related to windows forms development are found in System.Windows.Form.*.dll and all types related to web/asp.net development are defined in System.Web.*.dll. You can find these and related assemblies in GAC of the local machine.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean "where in memory does the data get stored - on the stack or on the heap" it gets quite complicated, and partly depends on the language.

I've written [an article about it](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/memory.html) which goes into more detail than I care to repeat here. Simplistic explanations such as the oft-repeated "value types live on the stack, reference types live on the heap" is hugely flawed, with the obvious counterexample of an `int` variable in a reference type - the value of that variable will always be stored on the heap, even though `int` is a value type.

However, you'd also be wise to read Eric Lippert's [blog post about the matter](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) - it's an implementation issue, and developers tend to get far too worried about it. The C# team *could* decide to change it all in a later version, and create a new object containing *all* local variables (instead of just captured ones).

Admittedly it's an *important* implementation detail - how much you put on the stack affects how deep your stack can be, etc - but we probably should spend so much time obsessing about it.

If this *isn't* what you intended the question to be about, please clarify it. For instance, you could mean:

- Where does type meta-data exist at execution-time?
- Where are the BCL types stored on disk?
- Where does the JIT-compiled code for types exist, and is it stored?

Answer (score -1):

They are 'stored' in various dll's.